# MVC Pass multiple parameters to controller including a list from the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to pass a list from the model and a string from my view to my controller.  I get the data from Home controller to the Dashboard.cshtml successfully, but when I try to pass a list from the model to the DetailController, the list doesn't go through but the string TicketGroupName does.  Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Dashboard.cshtml

```
@model testlogin.Models.DashboardViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@Model.AreaName</h2>

<table id="dashboardContainer" class="table">
    <tr class="data-row-1">
        <td class="tile text-center">
            <a href="http://company.html"><img style="height: 125px" id="Image1" src="https://logo.jpg" /></a>
        </td>
        <td class="tile btn text-center">
            <a href="@Url.Action("ShowTickets", "Detail", new { TicketList = Model.OpenNow, TicketGroupName = "Open Now" })">
                <div>
                    <div class="row tile-head">
                        <h4>Open Now</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <h1><strong>@Model.OpenNow.Count</strong></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Dashboard(string AreaName)
    {
        full_area_name = "Test Area";
        var dash = GetDashData(board_number); //Not including it here, but this method works
        dash.AreaName = full_area_name;

        return View(viewName: "Dashboard", model: dash);
    }
}
```

DashboardViewModel.cs

```
public class DashboardViewModel
{
    public List<TicketModel> OpenNow { get; set; }
}
```

DetailController.cs

```
public class DetailController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ShowTickets(List<TicketModel> TicketList, string TicketGroupName)
    {
        TicketViewModel vm = new TicketViewModel()
        {
            GroupName = TicketGroupName,
            Tickets = TicketList
        };
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

TicketViewModel.cs

```
public class TicketViewModel
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TicketModel> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

ShowTickets.cshtml

```
@model testlogin.Models.TicketViewModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="container">
    <div>
        <h1>@Model.GroupName</h1>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tickets.FirstOrDefault().TicketNbr)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tickets.FirstOrDefault().Company_Name)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tickets.FirstOrDefault().Priority_Description)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tickets.FirstOrDefault().Summary)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tickets.FirstOrDefault().Last_Update)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tickets.FirstOrDefault().OwnerOrCloser)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tickets.FirstOrDefault().Date_Entered_UTC)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tickets.FirstOrDefault().Date_Responded_UTC)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tickets.FirstOrDefault().Date_Closed_UTC)</th>
        </tr>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Tickets)
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You should not be passing the list via a GET action click link. You should just get it again in the `ShowTickets` action method.

Comment: You cannot pass a collection to a GET method using `Url.Action()` (look at the html you generating). You would need to pass each property of each item in the collection as a query string parameter which would be crazy and probably exceed the query string limit anyway). Get the collection again in the method.

Comment: I see.  I'll try that and post results.  Thanks for your help, both of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Shyju and @Stephen_Muecke, I rearranged my code in the controller to get the data again from the Http cache when the view called the action.

Just to make it clear in case anyone else is searching for this answer, you cannot pass a list (or IEnumerable) object from view to controller.  The list data has to be gathered again in the controller.

Thanks for your help, guys!